# 5 boys and 5 girls are standing in line. What is the probability that all the girls precede all the boys? (order otherwise doesn't matter)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $5$ girls and $5$ boys and they're lined up. What is the probability that all the girls are ahead of all the boys in line, assuming that other than that requirement the order does not matter?

This is a bit of a strange question that challenges my understanding. Typically the order *would* matter in this question, because the kids are lining up. In that case, I believe the answer would be $(5!)^2$

But if the order doesn't matter, and all the girls have to be before all the boys, how many possible lines are there? Is the answer just $1$...? I get the feeling that that's wrong but I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 5):

I assume the real question is this: if you randomly line up these $10$ people, what is the probability that the five girls end up in front of the $5$ boys?

Well, there are ${10 \choose 5}$ ways to pick the $5$ positions for the girls, and having them all in front is exactly $1$ of those, so the probability is $\frac{1}{{10 \choose 5}}$

And just to be clear: when they say the order does not matter, they mean that it doesn't matter how the $5$ girls are ordered (e.g. Is Jessica in front or Erica?  Well, we don't care about that) ... and same for the boys. We could also say that the girls are indistinguishable, and same for the boys.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Bram28 is correct.  The way I see this is to realize that you can place the first girl in $5$ of the $10$ possible spots.  Then you can place the second girl in $4$ of the remaining $9$ spots, etc., until you can place the last girl in $1$ of the remaining $6$ spots.  This yields a probability of $\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}$, which can also be written as $\frac{1}{\binom{10}{5}}$.